# Table columns have incorrect sizes in a popup

Tags: jquery, datatables

My aim is to simply implement fixed header on table with my `thead` and `tbody` to be scrollable.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="scroll1" id="style-3">
        <div id="empMasterFormMappingDetails">
            <div class="col-lg-12 WmpFrmAcc">

                    <table id="abc" border="1" style="width:100%;" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>A</th>
                                <th>B</th>
                                <th>C</th>
                                <th>Can View Can View Can View</th>
                                <th>Can Insert</th>
                                <th>Can Delete</th>



                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tbodyMasterFormMapping"></tbody>
                    </table>


            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>


  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#abc').DataTable({
                "scrollY": "250",
                "scrollX": true,
                "paging": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "info": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "autoWidth": true
            });
        });
</script>
```

In the above code `thead` and `tbody` is coming dynamically from other js.
Note : No inline styling is done to any `thead` and `tbody` or `th` or `tr` or `td`.

And the scrolling is possible but on pop up when the `thead` appears at the first time width of `thead` doesn't come according to t body but when i resize the window using mouse everything works fine. Why?

What I have done is I have given a fixed width to `thead`  but it doesn't apply. I have also used `!important` but none works.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You need to use [`columns.adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method **once table becomes visible** to recalculate the column widths.

```
$('#abc').DataTable().columns.adjust();
```

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29):

> This method is provided to have DataTables recalculate the columns sizes, based on the data in the table and the size applied to the columns (in the DOM, CSS or through the `columns.width` parameter). Call it when the table becomes visible if hidden when initialised (for example in a tab) or when the data changes significantly.
>
> DataTables will automatically call this method on the window `resize` event to keep the columns in sync with the re-flowed layout.

Comment: But exactly where ??? I should put  this $('#abc').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();